# Running Time of Decrementing Nested For Loop

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o

I recently had a programming interview and the following piece of code came up. The interviewer told me that it was an O(n*n) algorithm but I'm confused as to how that is, considering the inner loop runs fewer times each time the outer loop runs.

It's definitely not O(n) but why is it O(n*n)?

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at it this way. The first time through `i`, you're looping `j` 99 times. Next, 98, 97, 96, etc, all the way down to one. This is equal to:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ... + n
```

A quick way to sum these ([triangular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)) numbers is by using the technique [attributed to Gauss](http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.02.06/jo1.html):

```
sum = ((n * n) + n) / 2
```

Now you can clearly see the O(n*n).

Comment: Are you sure about this?  There's no n here - the loop always takes a fixed amount of time to run and the runtime doesn't grow.

Answer (score 0):

for i = 0: the inner loop runs 99 times
for i = 1: the inner loop runs 98 times
for i = 2: the inner loop runs 97 times
for i = 3: the inner loop runs 96 times
.
.
.
for i = 99: the inner loop runs 0 times

if we count the number of EOPs, say #(EOPs) := S, then S = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + .... + 99
so S = (99* (99 + 1)) / 2 <=> S = (99*99 + 99) / 2 => S <= 1/2 * 99^2 + 99 <=> S <= 99^2 + 99 <=>
S <= 99^2 + 99^2 <=> S <= 2* 99^2 so let n = 99 and c = 2, we get S <= c*n^2 then S has the order of n^2. The program fragment you comitted has because of that the order of n^2

Answer (score 0):

The running time complexity or the worst cast complexity of the algorithm is O(n*n). The simple reasoning behind this is from Mathematics,

When i = 0, j will run from j=1 to j = n (Takes n comparisons)
When i = 1, j will run from j=2 to j = n (Takes n-1 comparisons)
....
When i = n-1, j will run from j=n to j=n (Takes 1 comparison)

If you add this, (1) + (2) + (3) + ... + (n-1) + (n), you essentially calculate the sum of the first n natural numbers which is n*(n+1)/2. Expanding this you get (n*n + n)/2. This essentially has time complexity of n*n, or a big oh notation of O(n*n).